# I want to read all data stored in my RAM(word)through C++? What have I done wrong?

Tags: c++

```
//Program to check content of RAM(Kernel data?)
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int *a, b;

    while (a != NULL) //loop till memory end
    {
        a = &b;
        cout << "RAM " << a << "   " << *a << '\n';
        b++; //next address
    }
    return 0;
    //Output link below
}
```

As you can see '*a' shows output 0 at starting.
Why 'b' holds zero instead of a garbage value?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhIeM.png)

Comment: Ignoring all the *undefined behavior* due to uninitialized variables, `b` is just an integer - why would taking its address allow you to read RAM?

Comment: `b` is an `int`, not a pointer. It is always in the same place.

Comment: OK, I have tried moving 'a=&b' above 'while loop' and corrected 'b++' with 'a++' . This is my output- https://imgur.com/a/5e6Qc9x

Answer (score 3):

A program cannot (under normal circumstances) access all the RAM in a computer.

I suggest you read up on operating systems and systems programming fundamentals.

You can start with reading about virtual memory [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_management). I'll try to find a better link and add it.

**Edit:** You should also read: [Virtual Memory (Wikipedia)](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Virtual_memory) and [Virtual Address Space (Wikipedia)](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Virtual_address_space).

**Edit:** Just to answer your question formally, [userspace](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/User_space) processes don't have access to all the memory in your computer, they only have access to their own virtual address space. You need to be inside the kernel to access all the physical memory ie. you need to write your own kernel or write a device driver.

Answer (score 1):

As with many naive questions, the answers can be quite complicated :)
A simple answer is, not everything in your data address space (what you call "RAM") belongs to your program and is freely readable.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are in kernel mode you *cannot* read all physical RAM. You can only read the virtual address space allocated to your own process.